# Postgresql 11 logical replication - stuck in `catchup` state

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm running two postgresql 11 servers - master and slave (setup with logical replication).

The problem I'm facing is that today after weeks of uninterrupted work slave got out of sync with this error message:

```
2019-09-16 07:39:44.332 CEST [30117] ERROR:  could not send data to WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
2019-09-16 07:39:44.539 CEST [12932] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "logical_from_master" has started
2019-09-16 07:39:44.542 CEST [27972] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 30117) exited with exit code 1
```

I did see this error message before and my process was to increase `wal_sender_timeout` on master (more details on this here: [logical replication in postgresql - "server closed the connection unexpectedly"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245855/logical-replication-in-postgresql-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedly))

So then I wanted to restore replication however the state of replication is stuck on catchup:

```sql
master=# select * from pg_stat_replication;
  pid  | usesysid | usename | application_name  |  client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | backend_xmin |  state  |   sent_lsn   |  write_lsn   |  flush_lsn   |  replay_lsn  |    write_lag    |    flush_lag    |   replay_lag    | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------
 86864 |    16680 | my_user    | logical_from_master | 10.10.10.10 |                 |       46110 | 2019-09-16 12:45:56.491325+02 |              | catchup | D55/FA04D4B8 | D55/F9E74158 | D55/F9E44CD8 | D55/F9E74030 | 00:00:03.603104 | 00:00:03.603104 | 00:00:03.603104 |             0 | async
(1 row)
```

I tried to restart slave a few times, with different combinations of subscription enabled and disabled - nothing helps, the replication status keeps staying on `catchup`. I can see `sent_lsn` and `write_lsn` values are changing so something is being sent through...

This is my slave configuration:

```
wal_level=logical
max_replication_slots=2
max_logical_replication_workers=4

wal_receiver_timeout=1200000
```

And this is my master:

```
wal_level=logical

max_replication_slots=10
max_wal_senders=10

# maximum wait time in milliseconds that the walsender process on the active master
# waits for a status message from the walreceiver process on the standby master.
wal_sender_timeout=1200000
```

I have no idea what to do (even worst, at this stage I have no idea what to check next...)

Can you help me understand what should I do to make my slave to catch up so it's back to `streaming` state?

---

Edit (12 hours later)

When I checked in the morning synchronisation was still in `catchup` state

```sql
master=# select * from pg_stat_replication;
  pid  | usesysid | usename | application_name  |  client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | backend_xmin |  state  |   sent_lsn   |  write_lsn   |  flush_lsn   |  replay_lsn  | write_lag | flush_lag | replay_lag | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------
 12965 |    16680 | my_user    | logical_from_master | 10.10.10.10 |                 |       46630 | 2019-09-17 06:40:18.801262+02 |              | catchup | D56/248E13A0 | D56/247E3908 | D56/247E3908 | D56/247E3908 |           |           |            |             0 | async
(1 row)
```

But when I checked again 60 seconds later the results set was empty...

Logs now show multiple incarnations of the same error:

```
2019-09-16 22:43:33.841 CEST [20260] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
2019-09-16 22:43:33.959 CEST [26087] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 20260) exited with exit code 1
2019-09-16 22:43:34.112 CEST [3510] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "logical_from_master" has started
(...)
```

In order to make replication to show up as `catchup` on master I now have to restart slave first...

---

Edit (in response to @LaurenzAlbe comment)

I have rebuilt the replica yesterday morning and observed replication failing again starting from 19:53pm. Logs for master and for replica below:

```
2019-09-18 19:15:13.767 CEST [8611] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "logical_replica_from_master", table "lasttable" has finished
2019-09-18 19:54:14.875 CEST [11469] ERROR:  could not send data to WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
2019-09-18 19:54:14.969 CEST [10330] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "logical_replica_from_master" has started
2019-09-18 19:54:15.031 CEST [11217] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 11469) exited with exit code 1
```

Corresponding log from master:

```
2019-09-18 19:50:36.386 CEST,,,111051,,5d826e6a.1b1cb,1,,2019-09-18 19:50:34 CEST,138/28493452,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 8949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 43798 remain, 43783 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 17925 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.04 s, system: 0.05 s, elapsed: 1.88 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-18 19:51:36.402 CEST,,,1714,,5d826ea6.6b2,1,,2019-09-18 19:51:34 CEST,316/16529009,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 8949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 43798 remain, 43795 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 17925 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.07 s, elapsed: 1.87 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-18 19:52:36.421 CEST,,,2649,,5d826ee2.a59,1,,2019-09-18 19:52:34 CEST,153/19807659,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 8949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 43798 remain, 43795 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 17924 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.03 s, system: 0.05 s, elapsed: 1.87 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-18 19:53:36.424 CEST,,,2945,,5d826f1e.b81,1,,2019-09-18 19:53:34 CEST,317/15405278,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 8949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 43798 remain, 43795 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 17924 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.03 s, system: 0.05 s, elapsed: 1.88 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-18 19:54:15.123 CEST,"core","my_db",3073,"10.194.132.16:50372",5d826f47.c01,1,"idle",2019-09-18 19:54:15 CEST,317/0,0,LOG,00000,"starting logical decoding for slot ""logical_replica_from_master""","Streaming transactions committing after D5B/7A4D40, reading WAL from D5B/7A4D40.",,,,,,,,"logical_replica_from_master"
2019-09-18 19:54:15.124 CEST,"core","my_db",3073,"10.194.132.16:50372",5d826f47.c01,2,"idle",2019-09-18 19:54:15 CEST,317/0,0,LOG,00000,"logical decoding found consistent point at D5B/7A4D40","There are no running transactions.",,,,,,,,"logical_replica_from_master"
2019-09-18 19:54:36.442 CEST,,,3152,,5d826f5a.c50,1,,2019-09-18 19:54:34 CEST,362/5175766,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 8949 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 43798 remain, 43795 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 17924 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.02 s, system: 0.06 s, elapsed: 1.88 s",,,,,,,,,""
```

Then around midnight on slave:

```
2019-09-19 00:16:48.167 CEST [10330] ERROR:  could not send data to WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
2019-09-19 00:16:48.276 CEST [19530] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "logical_replica_from_master" has started
2019-09-19 00:16:48.324 CEST [11217] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 10330) exited with exit code 1
```

and corresponding log on master:

```
2019-09-19 00:15:41.104 CEST,,,74257,,5d82ac89.12211,1,,2019-09-19 00:15:37 CEST,78/34511468,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 13603 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 64816 remain, 64813 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 27234 hits, 0 misses, 1 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.003 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.03 s, system: 0.08 s, elapsed: 2.85 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-19 00:16:13.688 CEST,,,35656,,5d382555.8b48,11190,,2019-07-24 11:31:01 CEST,,0,LOG,00000,"checkpoint complete: wrote 1748 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=174.932 s, sync=0.000 s, total=174.936 s; sync files=75, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=11366 kB, estimate=13499 kB",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-19 00:16:41.121 CEST,,,75038,,5d82acc5.1251e,1,,2019-09-19 00:16:37 CEST,185/19338019,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 13603 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 64816 remain, 64813 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 27233 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.04 s, system: 0.07 s, elapsed: 2.85 s",,,,,,,,,""
2019-09-19 00:16:48.335 CEST,"core","my_db",75294,"10.194.132.16:50480",5d82acd0.1261e,1,"idle",2019-09-19 00:16:48 CEST,315/0,0,LOG,00000,"starting logical decoding for slot ""logical_replica_from_master""","Streaming transactions committing after D5B/1D1F1C0, reading WAL from D5B/1CA07F8.",,,,,,,,"logical_replica_from_master"
2019-09-19 00:16:48.335 CEST,"core","my_db",75294,"10.194.132.16:50480",5d82acd0.1261e,2,"idle",2019-09-19 00:16:48 CEST,315/0,0,LOG,00000,"logical decoding found consistent point at D5B/1CA07F8","There are no running transactions.",,,,,,,,"logical_replica_from_master"
2019-09-19 00:17:41.141 CEST,,,75484,,5d82ad01.126dc,1,,2019-09-19 00:17:37 CEST,330/18178915,0,LOG,00000,"automatic vacuum of table ""my_db.pg_toast.pg_toast_22314"": index scans: 0
pages: 0 removed, 13613 remain, 0 skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen
tuples: 0 removed, 64866 remain, 64863 are dead but not yet removable, oldest xmin: 3141915780
buffer usage: 27254 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
system usage: CPU: user: 0.04 s, system: 0.07 s, elapsed: 2.85 s",,,,,,,,,""
```

---

Edit

Following error message (on master) appears exactly after `wal_sender_timeout` time (from the time replication is enabled on slave):

```
2019-09-19 13:33:58.015 CEST,"core","nzdb",112432,"10.194.132.16:50886",5d8362f5.1b730,5,"idle",2019-09-19 13:13:57 CEST,379/2076197,0,LOG,00000,"terminating walsender process due to replication timeout",,,,,"slot ""logical_replica_from_master"", output plugin ""pgoutput"", in the change callback, associated LSN D5B/6782CF0",,,"WalSndCheckTimeOut, walsender.c:2100","logical_replica_from_master"
```

---

Edit

I added more RAM to that server but the observation is still the same - after `wal_sender_timeout` worker on slave logs the error mentioned above and on master I'm left with following in `pg_stat_replication`:

```
  pid  | usesysid | usename |              application_name              |  client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | backend_xmin |  state  | sent_lsn | write_lsn | flush_lsn | replay_lsn | write_lag | flush_lag | replay_lag | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------
 87820 |    16680 | core    | logical_replica_from_master_27004_sync_21691 | 10.10.10.10 |                 |       55548 | 2019-09-19 15:31:40.032662+02 |   3142872730 | startup |          |           |           |            |           |           |            |             0 | async
(1 row)
```

Then after a very long while it's back to catchup but with different `sent_lsn`

If I run `INSERT` to test table on master then I do not see changes on slave.

Comment: "I can see sent_lsn and write_lsn values are changing so something is being sent through"  Sounds like it got quite a ways behind, and is just taking a while to catch up.  How busy (in terms of writes) is the master?  Can you figure out the bottleneck on the replica?  Maybe you can use pg_prewarm or something to speed up the application of the logs.

Comment: I can see checkpoints happen roughly every 15 minutes and `iostat` is most of the time reporting no IO. Would you say this is replica not being powerful enough? On slave I have 4Gb of memory, both master and slave sit in the same rack.. From what I can see there is not so much of volume of data being pushed to master so the link should not be under stress...

Comment: `pg_stat_wal_receiver` is empty because WAL receivers are only run with physical replication. That's normal. I guess that replication is in `catchup` state regularly because it keeps being interrupted. The problem seems to be on the master server, which closes the connections unexpectedly. Could you add the master's log from the time of the slave error log entries to the question?

Comment: Many thanks @LaurenzAlbe, I added logs from master. On master I am not logging sql statements, I start thinking maybe I should increase log verbosity there...

Comment: I'll collect verbose logs next (`log_min_messages = 'INFO',
log_min_error_statement = 'INFO',
log_error_verbosity = 'VERBOSE',
log_replication_commands = 'TRUE'`
)

Comment: There is no indication of a problem in the master's log that anything is wrong. Perhaps a network problem (firewall) that drop connections?

Comment: Both  master and slave sit within same rack, there is no firewall between them. I wonder maybe this is caused by long transaction running on master and then when transaction is committed lots of data is being pushed, or maybe there is a table that contains a column (i.e. TEXT) with lots of data in it - do you think this could result in replication worker to die like this? Also I observe now that when replication worker dies pg_stat_replication on master does not show "catchup" anymore.. The replication does not start on its own anymore.

Comment: And also `pg_stat_replication` now shows `sent_lsn` with the same value all the time, like worker got stuck on one record (or maybe the record too big?)

Comment: Is there a reason you care?  If it is permanently catching up, but is only 3 seconds behind, what problems does that cause?  Is it better for it to have caught up completely at one time, but now be hours behind because it fell behind again?

Comment: Hi @jjanes - have a look at last update i left minutes ago, it's in catchup for the duration of `wal_sender_timeout`, then for a long time it's in `starting` state (but for random replication slot) and then back to catchup.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe do you think long transactions (like lasting a few days) can make replication to fail? or (for that matter...) deadlocks on replicated tables?

Comment: Not that I know.

Comment: Thanks! Then I'm clueless. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How to handle duplicate key error on original primary node which is now serving as standby node. So when subscription is started on primary and secondary is publisher, then subscription fails with duplicate keys error as primary already has the data before node went down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out your master database is too busy for single replication worker to handle all of the changes.

You need to cluster your tables - but make sure you do it in such way that tables with foreign keys are handled with the same worker, otherwise you might get into situation where foreign key constraint will prevent data from being inserted into one table because table foreign key points at had not been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

I underestimated how busy the master database was and that's because in July I observed replication working without errors. Apparently July is the month of holidays so the database sustained minimally less load for the problem not to manifest.

One of my colleagues pointed out that there is multiple processes writing to that database concurrently hence maybe single WAL sender is simply not coping with volume of information. This was very valid advice and afterwards I was scratching my head trying to think why have I not thought about that in the first place. @jjanes touched base in first comment about this too. I have put too much trust in how postgres adapts even with default options to such different workloads.

So what I'm doing now is to avoid using `CREATE PUBLICATION .. FOR ALL TABLES` and instead create multiple publications with multiple corresponding subscriptions on replica side.

Comment: How to handle duplicate key error on original primary node which is now serving as standby node. So when subscription is started on primary and secondary is publisher, then subscription fails with duplicate keys error as primary already has the data before node went down

Comment: I was using replicas to share the load to serve read-only clients, I never tested this in scenario you describe.. But my guess is that probably your new primary will have to stream everything back to your new secondary, but please don't count my word on this as I have not been using logical replicas in your scenario..